# How do I test an onKeyDown event on the whole document page for a pop up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, enzyme

I have a pop up and I would like to test that when I press `ESC` on my keyboard that the pop up closes.  The functionality works however I want to get my test to pass. I don't know how to simulate a `keyDown` press on the whole document and not just the Modal pop up component.

Here it my test right now:

```
  test("it should call the onKeyDown handler on key ESC press", () => {
    const onKeydownSpy = jest.fn();
    const component = mount(
      <div id="wrapper">
        <Modal
          isOpen={false}
          portalParent="#wrapper"
          onClose={() => {}}
          id="123"
        >
          <p>Modal</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );

    component.simulate("keydown", { keyCode: 27 });
    expect(onKeydownSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(onKeydownSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
  });
```

Here is my code:

```
  const handleKeyDownEvent = useCallback(event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      onClose();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDownEvent);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDownEvent);
    }
  }, [handleKeyDownEvent, isOpen]);
```

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're having is the document or one of the child elements needs to have the current "focus", if you check this before sending the esc key, what do you get:

```
document.hasFocus();
```

And generically you can:

```
document.focus();
```

before emitting your keys.

Comment: Hello so do you mean add `document.hasFocus();` where? in my code before i call the ESC key or in my test?

Comment: You would do it before emitting your key events, so probably it should be in your runtime code wrapped up in whichever function triggers this event. Then you wouldn't have to put it in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

> simulant.fire(document.body.querySelector('aside'), 'click')

```
 it('only triggers clickOutside handler when clicking outside component', t => {
    const onClickOutside = sinon.spy()
    enter code here
    ReactDOM.render(<Page onClickOutside={onClickOutside} />, document.body)
    simulant.fire(document.body.querySelector('aside'), 'click')
    t.equal(onClickOutside.callCount, 1, 'should fire when clicking menu sibling')
    document.body.innerHTML = ''
    t.end()
  })
```

Source: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/426